# Windows 10: Unable to use "Open with" on txt, jpg or png extensions. Opens only in default app

Tags: windows, windows-10, sublime-text-3

### Intro

In December 2018, I got myself a new ASUS N550JV laptop and I did a standard installation of Windows 10 Education 64-bit on the first day.

Everything works quite nicely, but there's one problem that's been bothering me for months now. In December, I even posted feedback about that on Microsoft Feedback Hub, but it seems like nobody pays attention to that.

Funny thing is that I also own a desktop PC, which also runs Windows 10 Education, and the same problem occurs.

### The issue

Let's talk about files with **.txt** extension. I prefer opening any textual files using *Sublime Text 3*. Windows uses *Notepad* by default, so my system opens .txt files using *Notepad* on double-click.

*Sublime Text 3* is installed on the system, and is located in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`.

After I right-click the .txt file, the "Open with" text is bold and the only offered option under that menu is, again, "Open with". Clicking this option **does absolutely nothing but ignores my command**.

I previously had Windows 7 installed on my PC, and I was able to use "Open with" context menu, as well as set *Sublime Text 3* as a default application for opening .txt files.

The same problem occurs with extensions **.jpg**, **.png**, **.pdf**, **.docx**, **.xlsx** and so on. Nothing happens after I press "Open with".

I tried setting the default app for .txt extension using a setting called *Choose a default app for each type of file* in Windows 10, but trying to change the app from *Notepad* to *Sublime Text 3* was impossible because Windows somehow thought that *Notepad* was the only available application.

It seems that even after some Windows 10 major updates during these 4 months, the issue has not been resolved. I'm starting to think that this isn't Windows-related.

### Screenshots

Using "Open with" on `.txt`: **Fail**

[image: open-with-problem-txt.png]

Using "Open with" on `.png`: **Fail**

[image: open-with-problem-png.png]

Using "Open with" on `.mp4`: **Success**

Some file types, like .mp4, are not glitched and it looks like this:
[image: open-with-working-mp4.png]

---

### System specs

#### DxDiag of my laptop

```
      Time of this report: 4/4/2019, 17:45:24
             Machine name:
               Machine Id:
         Operating System: Windows 10 Education 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)
                 Language: Croatian (Regional Setting: Croatian)
      System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
             System Model: N550JV
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 11/19/13 10:26:41 Ver: 04.06.05 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
                   Memory: 16384MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 15820MB RAM
                Page File: 11095MB used, 20595MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 120 DPI (125 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.17763.0001 64bit Unicode
```

#### DxDiag of my PC

```
      Time of this report: 4/4/2019, 18:04:08
             Machine name:
               Machine Id:
         Operating System: Windows 10 Education 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134) (17134.rs4_release.180410-1804)
                 Language: Croatian (Regional Setting: Croatian)
      System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
             System Model: P5K SE/EPU
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 10/20/08 15:00:31 Ver: 08.00.12 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9550  @ 2.83GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
                   Memory: 5120MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 5120MB RAM
                Page File: 5839MB used, 1455MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 144 DPI (150 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
                 Miracast: Not Available
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.17134.0001 64bit Unicode
```

## Update

I've previously attempted to set the default app for these extensions using **Choose a default app for each type of file** setting in Windows 10, but with no luck. For example, clicking on *Notepad* dropdown menu right next to .txt extension would give me *Notepad* as the only option. I tried this today (2019-04-04), and it gave me a couple of choices, including Sublime Text 3. Apparently this has been fixed, and I can now happily double-click .txt files and have them opened in my favorite text editor.

[image: settings-success-changed-notepad-to-sublimetext3.png]

**But**, I am still curious to know why the *right click -> **Open with** -> Open with* option does not work.

## Update 2

Thanks to [Win32Guy](https://superuser.com/users/542839/win32guy)'s answer in the first comment below, the issue was resolved quickly. Turns out **it was a shell extension blocking some other context menu items**. Using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks) I managed to detect a suspicious context menu item and I've disabled it.

It helps a lot if you **sort these items by "Microsoft" column**, to see which context menu items are not from Microsoft Corporation because one of these is probably causing the problem.

[image: shellexview-disabled-item.png]

Comment: May be a shell extension is causing the problem. See [Open-with list is collapsed; No items listed in the open-with menu](https://www.winhelponline.com/xp/openwithissue.htm)

Comment: **Exactly** that was the issue. An item called *PDFXChange Editor Context menu* located at `C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\Shell Extensions\XCShellMenu.x64.dll` was causing the issue. I disabled all context menu items from Tracker Software just to be sure.

Comment: So I waited 4 months for an answer from Microsoft, but you managed to resolve the issue in literally 15 minutes. You can post your answer so I can upvote it and choose as best answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a shell extension is causing the problem. Use ShellExView to narrow down the offending context menu shell extension.

[Open-with list is collapsed; No items listed in the open-with menu](https://www.winhelponline.com/xp/openwithissue.htm)